# Submit form refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>League of Legends Straw Poll</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <h1 class="text-center">Game Straw Poll</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- FORM -->
                        <form name="submitForm" id="submitForm" action="process.php" method="post">
                            <div class="row">   
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- GAME -->
                                    <select class="form-control" id="game-group" name="game" onchange="ChangeBackground();">
                                        <option selected disabled>Select your Game...</option>
                                        <option value="League_of_Legends">League of Legends</option>
                                        <option value="Heartstone">Hearthstone</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- QUESTION -->
                                    <div class="input-group" id="question-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Start typing your question...">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- OPTIONS -->
                                <div class="form-group form-group-options col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-option col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="options-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="option[]" id="option" class="form-control" placeholder="Options...">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- CHOICE -->
                                    <div class="checkbox" id="choice-group">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="choice" name="choice" value="Yes">Allow multiple choice
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Poll</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Poll created</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Share it: <a href="http://gamepoll.net/<?php echo $rand_value; ?>">http://gamepoll.net/<?php echo $rand_value; ?></a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Invia</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/addfield.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/changebackground.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='magic.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

An AJAX function into a js script

```
// magic.js
$(document).ready(function() {

// process the form
$('form').submit(function(event) {

    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
    $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'game'              : $('input[name=game]').val(),
        'question'          : $('input[name=question]').val(),
        'option'            : $('input[name=option[]]').val(),
        'choice'            : $('input[name=choice]').val()
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode      : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data); 

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
            if ( ! data.success) {

                // handle errors for game ---------------
                if (data.errors.game) {
                    $('#game-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                    $('#game-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.game + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                }

                // handle errors for question ---------------
                if (data.errors.question) {
                    $('#question-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                    $('#question-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.question + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                }

                // handle errors for option ---------------
                if (data.errors.option) {
                    $('#option-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                    $('#option-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.option + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                }

                // handle errors for choice ---------------
                if (data.errors.choice) {
                    $('#choice-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                    $('#choice-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.choice + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                }


            } else {

                // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

                // usually after form submission, you'll want to redirect
                // window.location = '/thank-you'; // redirect a user to another page

            }
        })

        // using the fail promise callback
        .fail(function(data) {

            // show any errors
            // best to remove for production
            console.log(data);
        });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

And a process.php

```
<?php
//Include configuration file
include('includes/config.php');

//Define variables
$question=$_POST['question'];
$game=$_POST['game'];
$option=$_POST['option'];
$choice=$_POST['choice'];

//Generate random number
$rand_value=rand();

//Create temporary folder
mkdir($rand_value);

//Copy page of Ask Poll
copy('page.php', $rand_value . '/page.php');
rename($rand_value . '/page.php', $rand_value . '/index.php');

//Add data into database
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die ("Errore di connessione!");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Impossibile selezionare database!");
$sql1="CREATE TABLE `" . $rand_value . "` (Question VARCHAR(200), Options VARCHAR(200), Choice INT(11))";
mysql_query($sql1) or die ("Impossibile eseguire la query!");

//Count number of Options available
$count=count($option);

    for ($i=0; $i<($count-1); $i++)
    {
        ${$sql . $i}="INSERT INTO `" . $rand_value . "` (Question, Options, Choice) VALUES ('$question', '$option[$i]', '$choice')";
        mysql_query(${$sql . $i});
    }   
?>
```

But when i send the form, the page redirect me to process.php

I don't want that the site refresh the page

EDIT

Werner, I followed your suggestion adding preventDefault but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Try writing `return false` in the bottom of the submit function.

Comment: Check my answer at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917084/jquery-form-post-php-empty-my-serialize-seems-to-be-failing/21917306#21917306

Answer (score 1):

You have an syntax error in your magic.js file. You should start by enabling your console and watch it for errors.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: input[name=option[]]
```

That is what I could read when pressing the submit button and then Escape just after that to stop the submit.

The problem lies the part where you create your formData. (Which you can actually create a lot easier with http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

You have a typo on line 15. Notice the extra brackets? You are not supposed to add the brackets even though they are in the name of the field. I recommend you to use the Serialize solution or at least select the fields using their IDs (that's what they are basically for).

```
$('input[name=option[]]') // Not valid
$('#option') // Better way to select a field
```

Hope this will get you in the right direction.